# What sets column width / distribution in Yii2's DetailView?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2, detailview

The same view, the same `DetailView`, the same code, different model, different end result:

[image]

What sets column width in this case? Why it is shifting with each record? Is this a Bootstrap or Yii2 issue? I tried to analyse generated code with Chrome Dev Tools, but got no conclusions. As you can see, there is a lot of empty spaces in both columns, so column width shifting should not occur.

Most important -- how to prevent that? How to make sure, that every view will look exactly the same, no matter what data will be printed inside `DetailView`?

Answer (score 7):

Also you can use the public propetry [template](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-detailview#$template-detail) to achieve this. For example:

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
   'model' => ...,
   'attributes' => [[...], [...]],
   'template' => "<tr><th style='width: 15%;'>{label}</th><td>{value}.</td></tr>"
]) ?>
```

In this case I have two columns where I am forcing the widht of first to 15% of total.

You can also use this approach to apply more style of your generated table.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to question in title (*What sets column width / distribution in Yii2's DetailView?*) is "*I don't know*" or "*Nothing sets this*". However, adding these lines:

```
table.detail-view th {
    width: 25%;
}

table.detail-view td {
    width: 75%;
}
```

to `site.css` is one of many approaches to "fix" this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.fix-width > tbody > tr > th {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```php
echo DetailView::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered detail-view fix-width'],
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' =>[],
]);
```

Comment: I'll be happy to accept your answer, but you must provide some text of explanation. Where to put these styles and code and why you decided to use exactly that code, not the other one. In generally, answers that consist of code examples only, without even a tiny explanation text are not welcomed in Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow and you can easily get your good answer downvoted just for this fact.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is the width of the contents. If you look carefully to the content  you see for different  witdh of content. Alias    different width of label column and value column. In this case the width is automatically manager by the widget. You can set them by css